# Effeciently parse and persist large data dumps

Tags: java, mysql

What's the fastest java library that can be used to parse through large `.sql` dump files - that only contain `insert` commands - and execute all of them? Perhaps some kind of multi-threaded library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To efficiently insert data into some MySQL database, the best solution is to use bulk inserts. The official  [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) can do it. [Benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11390363/395857):

```
InnoDB
Single inserts: 74148 ms
Batch insert: 84370 ms
Dirty bulk insert: 178 ms
Safe bulk insert: 118 ms

MyISAM
Single inserts: 604 ms
Batch insert: 447 ms
Dirty bulk insert: 63 ms
Safe bulk insert: 26 ms
```

Comment: *"Why not hibernate or spring data?"* - Perhaps because you didn't mention those as requirements ...